# Modifying jwt access token expiry time in django using simplejwt module

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer

from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView

from rest_framework_simplejwt.utils import datetime_to_epoch

SUPERUSER_LIFETIME = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):

@classmethod
def get_token(cls, user):        
    token = super(MyTokenObtainPairSerializer, cls).get_token(user)
    token['name']       = user.username
    token['user_id']    = user.id

    if user.is_superuser:
        #token.set_exp(from_time=starttime,lifetime=SUPERUSER_LIFETIME)
        token.payload['exp'] = datetime_to_epoch(token.current_time + SUPERUSER_LIFETIME)

    return token

class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
     serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

i have tried this code (followed this link: [How can we assign different expiry time to different users in jwt tokens in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827440/how-can-we-assign-different-expiry-time-to-different-users-in-jwt-tokens-in-djan) ). This code updates the expiry time of refresh token but i want to update expiry time of access token in django using simplejwt module. any suggestions please.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I just made a quick look to simplejwt github's page and you can customize some [settings](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt#settings) in your `settings.py` file;

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
}
```

**Updated Answer Based On Comment**

> thanks for response . but i want set globally jwt expiry time and later based on role , i want to override that expiry time . how is it possible??

As you say, you have to override default token generator method. But how?

First, create your own token obtain view that inherited from `TokenObtainPairView` and your own token obtain serializer that inherited from `TokenObtainPairSerializer`. After that, you can see that `validate` method create `access` and `refresh` tokens, so also you must override that method if you want to create token based on user role etc. After these steps you also have to change your `urls.py`.

Example;

```
import datetime

from django.utils.six import text_type

from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer

SUPERUSER_LIFETIME = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)


class MyTokenObtainSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super(TokenObtainPairSerializer, self).validate(attrs)
        refresh = self.get_token(self.user)
        data['refresh'] = text_type(refresh)
        if self.user.is_superuser:
            new_token = refresh.access_token
            new_token.set_exp(lifetime=SUPERUSER_LIFETIME)
            data['access'] = text_type(new_token)
        else:
            data['access'] = text_type(refresh.access_token)
        return data


class MyTokenObtainView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainSerializer
```

**`urls.py`**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/token/', MyTokenObtainView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair')
]
```

Comment: thanks for response . but i want set globally jwt expiry time and later based on role , i want to override that expiry time . how is it possible??

Comment: can customize ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME per user? means specific time for each user.